# How do we solve $2^x(4-x) = 2x + 4$, $x\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

> Find the integral solutions of: $2^x(4-x) = 2x + 4$.

Doing some manipulation and replacing  $x$ by $y + 1,$ I could get this:

$2^y = \dfrac{3 + y}{3 - y}$

But I couldn't solve any further.

On trying a few values of $x \in\{0, 1, 2\}$ worked and coincidentally the answer is $3.$

Is there any better approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that it $x>4$, LHS becomes negative while RHS is positive.

Also, if $x<-2$, RHS becomes negative while LHS is positive. So we have to manually check:
$$\{-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\}$$
We find that the only integral solutions are $x=0,1,2$.